# Flutter Custom Shape from png asset for a RaisedButton

Tags: button, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Like title says i would like to have a custom shape from an asset i draw for a RaisedButton and then edit the background color, splash color etc. I could draw it via CustomPainter but that is not really fast to do it if I have a lot of custom buttons.